# Force Akka network shape

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I'm trying to fast the fastest and most straightforward way of showing a Split Brain in Akka (akka-cluster).

To do this I would want 3 node processes but the 2 of them should only communicate with each other using the one in the middle so when I kill it a split would appear. It should look like this:


1--2--3

And kill 2 so that 1 and 3 can't communicate and the Split Brain Resolver handles it.

Or are there maybe easier ways to showcase a simple scenario of Split Brain and how the Akka Split Brain Resolver handles them?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the Split Brain Resolver, obviously because it is a premium feature :) . But, based on the description, the resolver activate work on timeouts also. So, why not actually block actor 2 when a certain message is received. So, set it up so it sleeps (with `Thread.sleep`) for a minute or two. That might be detected as a fail (again, working on intuition).

Another idea is to throw some kind of exception in your actor, and handle it with a `OneForOneStrategy` handler, mapping the `Throwable` to a `Stop` directive.